# regex phone numbers separated with commas

Tags: regex, validation

i need a regular expression to validate the field. It is a field of phone numbers, the number consists of 9 characters, numbers will be separated by commas.

Example:

```
123456789,123456789,123456789
123456789
123456789,123456789
```

I have written:

```
~^(([0-9]{9,9},)+|([0-9]{9,9})+)$~i
```

but validating passes only numbers with commas.

Example:

```
123456789,123456789,
123456789,
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a `*` quantifier to the first 9-digit group:

```
~^(?:[0-9]{9},)*[0-9]{9}$~
               ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ou7Pz9/1). No need in `~i` case insensitive modifier, there are no letters in the pattern. Also, `{9,9}` = `{9}`.

The same pattern can be written as

```
~^[0-9]{9}(?:,[0-9]{9})*$~
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ou7Pz9/2).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[0-9]{9},)*`  - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[0-9]{9}` - 9 digits
  - `,` - comma
- `[0-9]{9}`  - 9 digits
- `$`  - end of string (may be replaced with `\z` to match the very end of string).

EDIT: Since you only want to match comma-separated 9-digit chunks that only contain unique digits, it is possible to write a regex for that, although it is not recommended to use it. Best is to use your programming language means for that.

A regex will look like (verbose version):

```
^                      # start of string
 (                     # Group 1 start
  (\d)                 # Digit 1 captured into Group 2
  (?!\2)(\d)           # Digit 2 not equal to the first one
  (?!\2|\3)(\d)        # etc.
  (?!\2|\3|\4)(\d)
  (?!\2|\3|\4|\5)(\d)
  (?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)(\d)
  (?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7)(\d)
  (?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8)(\d)
  (?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8|\9)(\d)
 )
 (?:,(?1))*        # 0+ sequences of , and the Group 1 pattern
$                  # End of string
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ou7Pz9/3). A [one-liner](https://regex101.com/r/Ou7Pz9/4):

```
^((\d)(?!\2)(\d)(?!\2|\3)(\d)(?!\2|\3|\4)(\d)(?!\2|\3|\4|\5)(\d)(?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)(\d)(?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7)(\d)(?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8)(\d)(?!\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8|\9)(\d))(?:,(?1))*$
```

In PHP, you may just use

```
if (count( array_unique( str_split( $s))) == strlen($s)) {
    echo "Unique";
} else {
    echo "Not unique";
}
```

Comment: This is What do I need. Thanks :). Can this still be a unique number validation?

Comment: To say that each number given in my sample sequence is unique, may not be repeated

Comment: @Dranzi666 regular expressions are not powerful enough to check that all numbers in the string are distinct, afaik.

Comment: That is possible but it is not a good idea to use regex for this. I see you are using PHP, use something like [`if (count( array_unique( str_split( $s))) == strlen($s))`](https://ideone.com/JuOUjJ).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I believe that your regex tests that all _digits_ inside each number are unique, not that all _numbers_ listed are unique, doesn't it? It's even demonstrated on regex101 that you've provided.

Comment: @yeputons: Yes, that is how I understood the comment. Sorry, I used a wrong mention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your regex has to be very complicated:

```
^\d{9}(,\d{9})*,?
```

- It will match at least one number block consisting of 9 digits.
- Other 9 digit blocks might follow, if they are separated by a comma.
- The whole expression can end with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just move that plus(+) to the end of the bigger group

```
^(([0-9]{9,9},)|([0-9]{9,9}))+$
```