# comma separated phone number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

In the code below, I have a phone number field and what I want to achieve is make sure each number is 15 digits and also ensure that if multiple phone numbers are entered (comma separated) (see code to understand), they too are 15 digits.

```js
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
var regrExpr = new RegExp("^(?=\S{10,}$)(?=.*\d{15},?).*");
//var regrExpr = new RegExp("\d{15}(?:,\d{15})*");
//var regrExpr = new RegExp("\d{10,15}(?:,\d{10,15})*");
//var regrExpr = new RegExp("^(\d{15}[,]{0,1})+$");
//var regrExpr = new RegExp("^\+\d{10,15}(,\+\d{10,15})*$");
//var regrExpr = new RegExp("^(?=\S{10,}$)(?=.*\d{15},?).*");
    if (!regrExpr.test($("#txt").val())) 
   {
     alert("Please Enter No");
        return false;
   }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="tel" id="txt" style="width:300px">
<button id = "btn">Check</button>
```

Regex'ically, I need something like this :

```
~^[0-15]{15}(?:,[0-15]{15})*$~
```

[Found this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018747/regex-phone-numbers-separated-with-commas)

But, it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: What's with the tilde in the regex?

Comment: You are using a PHP way of declaring regex. `~`  are valid regex delimiters  in PHP PCRE, but not in JS `RegExp`. Are you  trying to write an HTML5 pattern? Then, you should not use regex delimiters at all. Use `pattern="\d{15}(?:,\d{15})*"`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You cannot use a backreference here, it will match identical comma-separated numbers.

Comment: @Ashish If the numbers are 10 to 15 chars long, you may try to just use `pattern="\d{10,15}(?:,\d{10,15})*"`. Please confirm you are just working on an on-submit validation that can be achieved with a mere HTML5 pattern.

Comment: Does this cover what you need?  `^(\d{15}[,]{0,1})+$` it validates the entire input, but does allow `,` at the end (see fiddle http://refiddle.com/refiddles/59915ddc75622d0c08160000)

Comment: FYI, `[0-15]` is a character class/set, this one in particular will only match the characters 0 through 1, and the character 5; not 0 through 15

Comment: All these patterns aren't working !

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but aren't you just looking for `[0-9]{10,15}`? [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/QCVSOV/2)

Comment: @ThomasMoors editing my question and code

Comment: Maybe also provide some sample input!

Comment: @ThomasMoors edited code !

Comment: With all do respect, but there still is no example input in your Q

Answer (score 1):

here is the working regular expression of your case.

```
^\+\d{10,15}(,\+\d{10,15})*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best regex would be

```
^(?=\S{10,}$)(?=.*\d{15},?).*
```

check the demo at [here](https://regex101.com/r/QCVSOV/1)

here

```
(?=\S{10,}$)
```

ensures that the string is atleast of length 10

```
(?=.*\d{15},?)
```

is responsible for matching if number is of 15 length and is comma seperated

Answer (score 0):

Use `/.../` notation to define regex:

```js
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
    var regrExpr = /^\d{15}(?:,\d{15})*^/;
    if (!regrExpr.test($("#txt").val())) {
        console.log("Invalid number, retry");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("All correct")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="tel" id="txt" style="width:300px">
<button id = "btn">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got a solution
 Check this Answer

```
var pattern = /^(?:\s*\d{15}\s*(?:,|$))+$/;

if(pattern.test($("#txt").val())){
  alert("Correct");
} else {
  alert("Wrong");
}
```

``